# Returning the URL from href attribute

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, href

I'm trying to grab a url from an href attribute and append and return it but I keep getting a "Cannot read property 'href' of null".

I've tried getting the value with document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS").href but that returns an undefined, then when I use the id I get the null error above.

This is my HTML:

```
<a class="js-link-name" id="js-link" href="{{ route('report.file.list')}}">Click Me</a>

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var questionnaires = [];

            @foreach($vm->getQuestionnaires() as $questionnaire)
            questionnaires.push(new window.app.locationReports.Questionnaire('{{ $questionnaire->getValue()  }}', '{{ $questionnaire->forDisplay() }}'));
            @endforeach

            new window.app.locationReports.LocationTiles($('.js-location-tiles'), $('.js-file-download-link'), $('.js-legend-trigger'), '{{ $vm->getUserViewPreferenceValue() }}', questionnaires, '{{ route('api.v1.reports.customer-satisfaction.recommend-to-others') }}', '{{ route('report.customer-satisfaction.locations.data.view-preference') }}');
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is my JS function:

```
buildLocationReportListUrl(){
        let newUrl = URI(document.getElementById('js-link').href).addSearch(this.locationId);

        return newUrl;
    }
```

Comment: When does that function run?

Comment: @Herohtar I'm calling it in the console. Once I have it working I will create a separate function that will add the new URL to the href attribute.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/r8qdfjxc/ Please create a [mcve] so we can reproduce the error you're getting. The error clearly points to the script running before the `<a>` exists.

Comment: Put a ```defer``` in your script tag just to make sure

Comment: @ChrisG I believe you're right. I've added a little more of my code so you can help me see where the issue could be.

Comment: Where, how and when is `buildLocationReportListUrl` called? It looks like you're using blade templating, so the key question is where your `scripts` stack is rendered inside the HTML document. Any JS command that relies on HTML elements must be run *after* the elements already exist. So if your `@stack` directive is in the `<head>`, that script will run *before* the `<a>` exists, and therefore `document.getElementById('js-link')` will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete. However when I tried your function with some modification it returns the URL.

```
function buildLocationReportListUrl(){
    let newUrl = document.getElementById('js-link').href;

    return newUrl;
}
```

//Execute the function to return URL

```
buildLocationReportListUrl();
```

Hope this helps! :)